# Microsoft Application Virtualization Client - QTP

Tags: virtualization, qtp, hp-uft

Our application has been changed from ".exe" to virtual application launched via "Microsoft Application Virtualization Client".

QTP is unable to identify any objects even with the same add-ins (which was working before). What could be the possible reason for the odd behaviour?
QTP : 10, Win7 64 bit OS.

Let me know for additional info. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think we would need a little more information than you're providing.  Is the object repository blank?  Are you able to add things to it?

Comment: All objects are identified as Winobject. Existing OR is of no use since QTP cannot able to identify objects.

Comment: So if you use the object spy for example and click a button on your application, what is returned is just the browser window?  Rather than the actual element you clicked?  When using the object spy, does it box things like it does see them or doesn't react at all?

Comment: Yes, when i try to spy a button it shows Window().Winobject(). QTP does box few objects, but not always. Only for selected objects like button, webedit etc. When i try to spy a link, it identifies all links as a group.

Comment: on [msdn](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee958112.aspx) they mention that each virtual app is running in its own container. UFT identifies components (things like MFC objects or dot net objects ) that are children of a window object. If the app is virtual, is it possible that UFT cannot access the components as they are not strictly speaking there at all - they do not exist in memory as individual blobs of code, they don't have handles to hook.

Comment: I have not used them but , if all else fails [Virutal Objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/qtp/qtp_virtual_objects.htm) may be a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

When this application is launched via Microsoft Virtual Client it has limited interaction with local applications. For the same reason `QTP\UFT` is unable to identify the object of AUT. To overcome this issue you have to set `"LOCAL_INTERACTION_ALLOW" to TRUE` in the Application OSD file.
You can find the file in the `OSD Cache` folder in the program data of Microsoft Virtual Client.